# Configuring ACS

Tags: c#, azure, acs

I have a scenario with a Ecommerce website where I want the user to be prompted for a sign in with Google just before he proceeds to order an item after adding it to the cart. Now, the challenge is to configure the authentication using windows azure's ACS only at a certain point of action and not when the user hits the website. How do we configure the realm settings and other related items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [this very simple approach](http://www.leastprivilege.com/MixingFormsAndTokenAuthenticationInASingleASPNETApplication.aspx) for an ASP.NET MVC. Actually I mix N2 CMS in MVC mode along with ACS authentication. My scenario is exacly like yours - I want a claims authentication only at certain areas of the site (actually only certain Actions of a Controller).

If your application is an ASP.NET MVC it is super easy to implement following the details on [that blog post](http://www.leastprivilege.com/MixingFormsAndTokenAuthenticationInASingleASPNETApplication.aspx). For classic ASP.NET Web Forms seems to be trickier, and unfortunatelly I haven't tried it, because my solution is ASP.NET MVC.